# JSF 2.2 html5 friendly page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

Some sources indicate that it's possible to use non-obtrusive jsf:id attributes in a JSF2.2 page.

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2012/11/01/html5-friendly-markup-jsf-22
http://www.apress.com/9781430244257

The taglib descriptors use different urls. 
From the weblog:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf">
<head jsf:id="head">
```

From the book:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"> 
<head jsf:id="head>
```

However, while using the newest JSF2.2 implementation (2.2.0-m15), both urls for the tag descriptors are unreachable (CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB), resulting in a partially unparsed html page.

Where to find the correct urls for the jsf tag library? Is there some kind of index for those urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is the correct definition. I don't think the `head` tag is used that way with JSF. Use the JSF `html` tag library.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <h:head></h:head>
....
```

You typically use `jsf:id` for HTML5 input components. Refer to the [Java EE 7 Tutorial section on HTML5/JSF pass-through](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm#BABGECCJ) for information and an example application.

Answer (score 2):

To use `jsf:id` use http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf namespace. This is applicable for form input. It is not used on head tag. For example, the following code declares the namespace with the short name jsf:

```
        <html ... xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
         ...
       <input type="email" jsf:id="email" name="email"
       value="#{reservationBean.email}" required="required"/>
```

Here, the jsf prefix is placed on the id attribute so that the HTML5 input tag's attributes are treated as part of the Facelets page.